# MEDIA_ROOT: shall I hardcode the path or use os.path.join?

Tags: django

**Django 1.11**

The documentation shows that we should place, say, images to
/var/www//media/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root

But in the book "Two Scoops of Django" they recommend:

```
# Configuring MEDIA_ROOT
# ’DONT DO THIS! Hardcoded to just one user's preferences
MEDIA_ROOT = "/Users/pydanny/twoscoops_project/media"
```

And then suggest their way:

```
root = lambda *dirs: join(abspath(BASE_DIR), *dirs)
# Configuring MEDIA_ROOT
MEDIA_ROOT = root("media")
```

Do you accept the way Two Scoops of Django recommends?
In this case MEDIA_ROOT will be inside the project itself. This is bad, I think. This is somehow a mix of code and user data.

So, I like what the documentation of Django recommends: just hardcode a path to /var/www/example.com/media/.

MEDIA_ROOT is not even STATIC_ROOT. Static files are collected from inside the project. And they contain something which is more or less (CSS) a code. Whereas user uploaded files are definitely the data, not the code.

Could you comment? What your MEDIA_ROOT looks like? 
Shall I use different MEDIA_ROOTS for my local machine and the production serve?

Comment: I prefer using hardcoded. Thus I have two different settings.py; one for production and one for the development machine. I have to note that this is not just for the media root settings but i also use the other settings differently in dev and prod.

Comment: Is it suitable for a team? You have one server for production. And what is hardcoded is not that horrorable: it is suitable for this very server. But your teammate work on their own machines.

Comment: Simply if you do not add your development settings.py into version control system. They can all have their own development settings.py so it does not so hard to adopt it to team.

Comment: Does your media_root point to var/www/<project_name>? I mean that "www" has these permissions: drwxr-xr-x  5 root root . This may somehow be not very convenient. If you create a directory inside www, you will have to allow django process to write inside it.

Comment: No, It does not contain <project_name> so it is not under my project folder i usually prefer one folder upper for the media root because this is usually where i also populate my virtualenv files and this way, it also does not bother with version control systems. I also does not keep my projects under /var/www/, I usually use someother path that i create on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I once used following :

```
ENV_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, 'media/')
```

This will automatically detect the absolute path to the settings.py file and create media_root path.

Comment: Inside the project? I mean, why it is inside the project and not in var/www?

Comment: Yes, You can create .env file and set your media_root to whereever you want. Creating .env file is not a convention but an efficient way so that we can change in a single file.

Comment: Why do you keep uploaded files inside the project? Is it beneficial?

Comment: As per django documentation, it has given an example of absolute path:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root

There is nothing about preferences or beneficial part.

Comment: No. It is not just an example of absolute path. The documentation teaches best practices. It is often mentioned when improvements to Django documentation are discussed.

Comment: right. It teaches best practices. I should change my current ways of doing it. Thanks